# Combine for loop and sql in java

Tags: java, sql

I have 2 input dates: `myStartDate`,`myEndDate` and a table `TEST_TABLE` with columns

```
TEST_ID, TEST_USER,TEST_START, TEST_END
```

I need to check if the range of dates between myStartDate and myEndDate have corresponding records in the TEST_TABLE.
I also need to ensure that I don't retrieve duplicate records.

Here's a sample of the logic I have so far:

Assuming,

```
myStartDate=06/06/2012;myEndDate=06/09/2012
int diff = myEndDate - myStartDate; //In this case = 3

String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE"+ myStartDate +"BETWEEN TEST_START AND TEST_END OR "+ (myStartDate +1) +" BETWEEN TEST_START AND TEST_END OR"+ (myStartDate+2)+"BETWEEN TEST_START AND TEST_END OR"+(myStartDate+3)+"BETWEEN TEST_START AND TEST_END";

List <TestTableData> myList = new List();
//Exceute query & save results into myList using add method
```

Want to know if there's any way to test the range of dates between myStartDate &myEndDate using a `for loop` in java code, instead of the approach used above in `myQuery`.Also, how can I avoid duplicates.

New to Java so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A for loop in java (or other) on all select result?, yes. To check duplicates use an array and put the single item see in loop, control the next with that and continue (discard the next if is in see array)

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to select. Do you want all the rows whose range of dates overlaps the range [myStartDate, myEndDate], or do you want all the rows whose range of date is completely inside [myStartDate, myEndDate]? Your query doesn't even use myEndDate at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ResultSet` to iterate over the output, like the code below.

```
while (res.next()) {
        String col1= res.getString("col1");
        String col2 = res.getString("col2");

      }
```

If you use an `Array` implementation , it does not allow for duplicate elements and hence there is no need to check for one.

But if you must use a list then , you could use the following code to remove any duplicate elements.

```
public static void removeDuplicates(List list)
  {
    Set set = new HashSet();
    List newList = new ArrayList();
    for (Iterator iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
      Object element = iter.next();
      if (set.add(element))
        newList.add(element);
    }
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(newList);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking are some generic questions about how to read a database and how to handle dates in java. I will give you some sample code below. But I suggest you look at the java database tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html and the java.util.Date api doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html for more info.

Here is some sample code that specifically demonstrates how to implement your question:

```
    // get the input dates
    // they are hard coded in this example
    // but would probably normally be passed in
    String startDateStr = "2/3/03";
    String endDateStr = "3/1/03";

    // unfortunately, there are 2 "Date" classes in this code and you need to differentiate
    // java.util.Date is the standard java class for manipulating dates
    // java.sql.Date is used to handle dates in the database
    // name conflicts like this are rare in Java
    SimpleDateFormat dateFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yy");
    java.util.Date myStartDate = dateFmt.parse(startDateStr);
    java.util.Date myEndDate = dateFmt.parse(endDateStr);

    // conneect to the database
    // I am using mysql and its driver class is "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    // if using a different database, you would use its driver instead
    // make sure the jar containing the driver is in your classpath (library list)
    // you also have to know the url string that connects to your database
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); // loads the driver
    Connection dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(
       "jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb", "(db user)", "(db password)"
    );

    // get the database rows from the db table
    // my table is named "testtable"
    // my columns are named "DateStart" and "DateEnd"
    Statement st = dbConn.createStatement();
    String sqlStr = "Select * from testtable";
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlStr);

    // loop through the rows until you find a row with the right date range
    boolean foundRange = false;
    while (rs.next()) {
        java.util.Date dbStartDate = rs.getDate("DateStart");
        java.util.Date dbEndDate = rs.getDate("DateEnd");
        if (myStartDate.before(dbStartDate)) continue;
        if (myEndDate.after(dbEndDate)) continue;
        foundRange = true;
        break;
    }

    if (foundRange) {
        // code that executes when range is found in db
    } else {
        // code that executes if range not found in db
    }

    dbConn.close();
```

Hope this helps you get started.